# Why can't we await a Mutiny Uni inside a @RunOnVirtualThread method?

Tags: quarkus, vert.x, mutiny, quarkus-reactive, virtual-threads

Assuming we have one part of our system as reactive code using Mutiny, and now we want to use Virtual Threads using imperative programming and bridge both worlds.

**Instinctively I'd do this:**

```
@Blocking
@RunOnVirtualThread
public SomeItem runOnVirtualThreadAndWaitUni(){

    var someItem = doHeavyWorkWithUniResponse().await().indefinetly();

    return someItem;
}
```

**Which however produces:**

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The current thread cannot be blocked: vert.x-eventloop-thread-3

Why can't we wait for the Uni to finish, despite the `@Blocking` annotation?

Comment: Who calls the `runOnVirtualThreadAndWaitUni()` method? The `@Blocking`, `@NonBlocking` and `@RunOnVirtualThread` annotations only make sense when the method is called by the container (Quarkus).

Comment: @Ladicek in my case the method is called from the Rest Resource's endpoint. Do I understand you correctly that these annotations can only sit on the endpoint method itself?

Comment: Yes, you should put the annotation on the resource method.